# RequiresAuthentication equivalent for WCF

Tags: wcf

I am using Windows Authentication and my question is, what would be the equivalent of the ReuiresAuthentication attribute that RIA services uses? I would like somthing similar to it to use in Plain WCF service. Any examples of how to implement security in plain WCF service?  Thanks.